# Zend database ACL not updating new privilege cache issue

Tags: zend-framework, memcached, acl

I am new in Zend Framework.

I am working on a code which has DB driven ACL. Also uses Memcache.

The problem is that even after a new privilege has be assigned/changed it is not reflecting until all the session is cleared.

I tried clearing the cache via zend_cache cleaning_mode_matching_tag.

Do I need update/delete something in zend session ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: The session is stored in the database? But cached in memcache? What is the lifetime for the cache? Can you expire this manually

Comment: Session is not stored in db, the ACL roles and permissions are. Cache lifetime is 3600sec. I am deleting the cache via $cache->clean(Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_TAG, $tags) and $cache = $this->_cachemanager->getCache('long')->remove($cacheId);

Comment: How can you check if the cache is being removed or not ? Can i do var_dump of the cache ?

Comment: yes, get the cache & var_dump it. So the session is cached but still stored in the traditional place of the file system? Better not to cache the session, but store it in memcache & update rather than delete as it will log the user out